# Проблема с типами: ctypes.pointer ведёт к ошибке TypeError: _type_ must have storage info

Tags: python, c, указатели, динамические-массивы, ctypes

У меня есть библиотека mul.so на си, в которой содержится вот такая функция(перемножает матрицы a и b в thcount потоков и возвращает результат):

```c
double** mul_m(double **a, double **b, int n, int thcount) {
         //...
}
```

Я хочу использовать эту функцию в коде на питоне, с помощью Ctypes.
Вот как я это пытался делать:

```
import ctypes as ct

mul_m = ct.CDLL("./mul.so").mul_m
mul_m.argtypes = [ct.pointer(ct.pointer(ct.c_double)),ct.pointer(ct.pointer(ct.c_double)), ct.c_int ]
mul_m.restype =  ct.pointer(ct.pointer(ct.c_double)
```

Но этот вариант не сработал(ошибка `TypeError: \_type_ must have storage info`).
Помогите разобраться, как я могу использовать эту функцию в коде на python, как вызвать ее, какие данные можно ей подать(в библиотеке есть еще функция, которая генерирует массив double**, но можно ли как - то подать, например, питоновский list(list()))

Comment: Используйте просто a@b, где a,b numpy массивы. Эта операция numpy.dot вызывает, которая может несколько потоков использовать. 2- ctypes.pointer и ctypes.POINTER это разные вещи

Comment: 3- [указатель на указатель может быть не самый эффективный интерфейс](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17259877/4279). Рассмотрите возможность использования плоского указателя (с `n*i*+j` индексированием). 4- Старайтесь в одном Stack Overflow вопросе, одной проблемой ограничиваться (задайте несколько самодостаточных вопросов если необходимо).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы тип указателя задать (`int*`), следует использовать `ctypes.POINTER(c_int)` вместо `ctypes.pointer(c_int)` (последнее пытается конкретный указатель получить (`&int`), что смысла не имеет).

К примеру, вот как можно распечатать [`char **environ`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html#tag_08), используя `ctypes`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import ctypes

lib = ctypes.CDLL(None)
env = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_char_p).in_dll(lib, 'environ')
print(*iter(lambda it=iter(env): next(it), None), sep='\n')
```

Печатаем `char*` C строки (`b'\0'`-terminated—представлены как `bytes`) пока нулевой указатель не встретится (представлен как `None` здесь). Используются [обе формы `iter()` вызова](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter): `iter(iterable)` и `iter(function, terminator)`.

#### Вывод

```
b'LANGUAGE=en_US:en'
b'LC_ADDRESS=en_GB.UTF-8'
b'LC_MONETARY=en_GB.UTF-8'
b'PAPERSIZE=a4'
b'SESSION=ubuntu'
...
```

Обычно можно эти значения через `os.environ`, `os.environb` получить (могут быть тонкие отличия).